# How to get the array keys of arrays inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a collection that has 2 arrays like on this picture:

[image]

So there are:

```
array 63 has two keys 70 and 72
array 64 has key 71
```

What i want to do is to get the keys 70, 72, 71.

How to get those keys??

Comment: Have you tried nested foreach?

Comment: no...can you point me to a direction

Comment: Sorry I meant nested foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$keys = $collection->flatMap(function ($item) {
    return array_keys($item);
});
```

---

If you think there may be duplicates, tack on a call to `unique` at the end:

```php
$keys = $collection->flatMap(function ($item) {
    return array_keys($item);
})->unique();
```

Comment: That's what I call "slam & dunk"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$keys = [];
$collection->each(function ($item) use (&$keys) {
    $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($item));
});
```